# RVM setting default ruby is temporary

Tags: ruby, rvm

So I've been trying to set my default Ruby version to 2.1.2, but I also have 2.0.0 installed and use it occasionally. When I run the command `rvm use --default 2.1.2`, it works, displaying `Using /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2` like it should. If I run `ruby -v`, it returns 2.1.2. Everything's fine there.

However, if I open a new terminal window, and I run `ruby -v`, it displays 2.0.0. If I do `rvm list`, it displays the following:

```
➜  ~  rvm list

rvm rubies

=> ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

It basically says that version 2.1.2 is the default, but it is currently using 2.0.0. I don't understand why this would happen, if it is the default, it should start up using that one.

Comment: I'm using Oh My ZSH! if it matters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rvm --default use 2.1.2
```

.......................................

Comment: I just had to restart my computer and then it worked.

Comment: @HobbitHole, I don't believe that restarting your computer did anything.  After I run that command, rvm switches to ruby 2.1.2, and then if I do `rvm list`, rvm indicates that the current and default ruby is 2.1.2.  If open a second window, and change the default in the first window, even the second window will show the new default--although the second window's current ruby will remain what it was before I changed the default.  What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on Fedora 20. My computer has lots of issues so it's probably just that something was misconfigured and I somehow fixed it between when I posted this question and today because it magically works now.

Answer (score 1):

Close, but not quite.  From `rvm help use`:

> To set a ruby as the user default, use the --default option.
>
> ```
> $ rvm use 1.9.3 --default
> ```

edit: as 7stud posted, it works with `--default` before as well, just not in the middle.